# which level are you in?

Tags: grammaticality

can someone tell me which of following questions is correct or tell me if both are correct?

"In which level are you?"

"Which level are you in?"

A little more information about is that the question is regarding school courses levels.

Any help resolving this little puzzle will be appreciated.

Comment: The first sounds overly formal. That said, most people would use "on" with "level" instead of "in". Comes from the idea of a level being a floor that you would literally stand on.

Comment: Thank you very much ColleenV that cleared my mind a little bit.

Comment: Now my question is, can I use the second one?

Comment: Both are fine. The second one is probably better in most contexts of actual usage.

Comment: Thank you Kappler all my questions have been answered regarding this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oxforddictionaries.com one of the definitions of *level* is *a social, moral or intellectual standard* and it requires the preposition *at*

> at an advanced (intermediate ) level

Comment: True, but there are other meanings of _level_ that do not require the preposition "at."

Comment: If you read the question, It's about school, courses levels.

Comment: I read the question.  For some uses related to school _at_ works fine.  _He is reading at a fourth-grade level._  For some "on" is better: _He is stuck on level three of the programming series._  Another option is "in:" _He is much happier now that he is in level three Spanish classes._  (AmE)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting preposition question.

**Using "in"**

> What level are you **in**?

refers to the grade level a student would be in

> **What level is he in?**
>   *What grade is he in?*
>
> He's in Form 4  *(BrE)*
>   He's in Fourth Grade *(AmE)*

**Using "at"** and "**on**"

> What level are you **at**?
>   What level are you **on**?

can refer to how far along one is in their course of study or gaming

> **I'm at level 10** *( out of 20 )*
>   **I'm on the intermediate level**

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the preposition *'at'*!

You reach **at** certain levels in academics or hierarchy in an office.

Said that...

> *Which level you are at?*

can be answered...

> *I'm at an advanced level*.

or...

> *I'm at a managerial level* responsibile for all the operations of the mall.

Answer (score 1):

Some people think that it's wrong to end a sentence with a preposition  - a "dangling preposition". These people think that the second sentence is wrong, and the first sentence is 'correct'. Everybody else thinks that the first sentence is too formal and complicated, so they let their prepositions dangle, as in sentence two.

Regarding the choice of preposition, you can be **in** group of people, for example a class or year. You can be **at** or **on** an academic level or stage.